# squealing sound turning steering wheel when engine is cold

Tags: power-steering

Squeals when turning steering wheel, only when engine is cold. Fluid has been checked and is full; when warmed up the sound goes away.

Comment: Check the drive belt for the power steering pump, both its condition and for correct tightness.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Could you please give us the year/make/model/engine of the car in question?

Comment: As noted, tighten the loose belt.